# How to get Facebook Stories Api as Json

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am developing app which can fetch facebook stories by using facebook api and return json to app for display. I searched on different plateform to get some help to do that, but i can't see any useful information about fb stories api.

Comment: I am pretty certain these are not available via API.

Comment: so how can i do this ?

Comment: You simply can’t. Scraping or anything like that is not allowed.

Comment: In any way you  know how to fetch stories videos?